# What does "knowledge nugget" mean?

Tags: idioms

I understand that it's a "piece of information", but does it also imply, that the information is valuable? Can a paragraph of text about a subject be a knowledge nugget? If so, can it contain several small pieces of information, or it must be information about single subject? In other words: knowledge nugget is just one simple fact, or several facts about single subject?

Is this a common, neutral expression, used in daily life, or it sounds odd?

Comment: [A knowledge nugget is a small item or piece of useful knowledge in categories of interest to the user](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-lEnWbgNNh0C&pg=PA57&dq=%22knowledge+nugget%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=o2hFT9buFtOzhAebzuX1AQ&ved=0CE8Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22knowledge%20nugget%22&f=false). It's "business trainers' jargon", not a general purpose idiom. I think most people would say they had a **useful snippet** for a small, simple, interesting item of information.

Comment: Don't use it in daily life. Use it in the appropriate context to the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks FumbleFingers, I didn't know the "useful snippet" expression.

Comment: I've used the phrase "nugget of knowledge" in ordinary conversation. I was describing to a colleague how most of the material he was reading for a project was, to be polite, compost, but it contained a few nuggets of useful knowledge.  "knowledge nugget", however, sounds like it belongs on a Powerpoint slide.

Comment: @Artur Nowak: Google Books says it has many thousands of references to ["snippet of information"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22snippet+of+information%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). *Snippet* is definitely the normal word - *nugget* isn't ridiculous, but it's certainly not in common usage.

Answer (score 5):

*[Nugget](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nugget)* has multiple senses that include

> (countable) A small, compact chunk or clump. (*eg*) a gold nugget
>   (countable) A tidbit of something valuable. (*eg*) a nugget of wisdom

As a consequence, one can argue either way regarding implication of value.  Of course, your example, *knowledge nugget* is closely analogous to "a nugget of wisdom" (an example from wiktionary).  The definition offered in [a link](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-lEnWbgNNh0C&pg=PA57&dq=%22knowledge+nugget%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=o2hFT9buFtOzhAebzuX1AQ&ved=0CE8Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22knowledge%20nugget%22&f=false) in a previous comment, that "A knowledge nugget is a small item or piece of useful knowledge in categories of interest to the user", also implies value.

Comment: Thank you jwpat7, would you agree with FumbleFingers that it's "business trainers' jargon"? If I would say "nugget of knowledge" in response to friend's story, which is interesting to me, would I sound odd?

Comment: @ArturNowak - I can't answer the latter question, as I don't know how you usually sound, but can say that using "nugget of knowledge" occasionally (eg, a few times per year) in conversation won't itself make you sound odd.

Comment: @ArturNowak: I agree with jwpat that occasional usage of *"nugget of knowledge"* is well within the bounds of normal conversation (though I still think *"snippet [of information]"* is more common). It's the condensed form *"knowledge nugget"* that strikes me as more "business training course lecturer's jargon".

Comment: Thanks, I thought that "nugget of knowledge" sounds a little pretentious, probably it does when used too often :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that *nugget* implies value. Gold nuggets are only valuable because they are gold. Chicken nuggets on the other hand, well, I wouldn't call them valuable.

A knowledge nugget implies that the information is small and self contained. That is what nugget implies to me. A nugget of knowledge wouldn't need any more explaining to be understood, and it wouldn't take long to understand.

In reply to FumbleFingers: Certainly in its origin of the gold rush in America, [nugget](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=nugget&searchmode=none) meant something valuable. However these days you can have a nugget of [dung](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22nugget+of+dung%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), [shit](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22nugget+of+shit%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), [hate](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22nugget+of+hate%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and even nuggets of [bile](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22nugget+of+bile%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) and [pain](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22nugget+of+pain%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), so I doubt that all nuggets are valuable. I maintain that a nugget's worth is based on what it is a nugget of, not that it is a nugget.

Comment: -1: Chambers - *Nugget: a lump, esp. of gold; anything small but valuable (fig.)* Chicken nuggets may have devalued the word, but are we to allow ad-men to control the language?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: not ad-men, but common usage.

Comment: I think of a nugget as a small, hard, chunky object. There are a few football (Australian, rugby and rugby league variants) players nicknamed Nugget for exactly that reason. The value comes from what the nugget is made of, not its nuggetyness.

Comment: @Optimal Cynic: I didn't include the rest of my UK Chambers definition there - interestingly, it goes on to say **(Australian) thick-set, stocky**.